# HttpPost with parameters not working to ASP server

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient

I need to create an HttpPost request with two parameters. I agree there are many examples, but I believe I've done my research but still I am not getting a response from the ASP server. I've tried NameValuePair but I can't seem to get the response page. I am guessing the parameters are not being added to httpPost object.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", id.getText().toString()));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pword.getText().toString()));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

String responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
Log.d("response to string", responseContent);
```

I am getting the login page again, and this code returns a NullPointerException:

```
String newURL = response.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please submit logcat to expect more helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just miss `?` at the end of your url

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
private static String urlAppendParams(String url, List<NameValuePair> lNameValuePairs) {
    if (lNameValuePairs != null) {
        List<NameValuePair> llParams = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
        for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : lNameValuePairs) {
            llParams.add(nameValuePair);
        }

        String sParams = URLEncodedUtils.format(llParams, "UTF-8");
        if (!url.endsWith("?")) {
            url += "?";
        }
        url += sParams;
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked with the params, but i am not getting any response

EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) gives me nothing.

Comment: that is probably a problem on the backend or you are calling the backend in a wrong way.

Comment: i am sorry, im a beginner, and very new to web development, could you please clarify what you mean, and perhaps tell me how to do it the right way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you arrive at the home page with the browser (https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp), the server opens the session (you can see the set-cookie header with the network inspector):

```
Set-Cookie:ASPSESSIONIDQCCCQQCQ=HJMMOCFAFILCLNCJIMNBACIB; path=/
```

Probably you will need to make a GET request to this page BEFORE the POST login. I addition, you have to enable the cookie tracking in the HttpClient. I normally use:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
final HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp");
client.execute(get); //perform an initial GET to receive the session cookie

//now do the post...
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp?Summit=OK");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hcUserID", id.getText().toString()));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hcPassword", pword.getText().toString()));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

//I should be logged in.... Lets get the an internal webpage
get = new HttpGet("https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/std_Alert.asp");
client.execute(get);

System.out.println(new String(get.getResponseBody()));
```

Since I do not have a valid user/password, I could not try this solution.

Comment: i cannot seem to find the setCookiePolicy() method? nor the executeMethod() i can only find execute()

you could try using this username and password
username chsac1203
password 1234567k
please update me ASAP

Comment: Mmmm, maybe I am talking in an old Httpclient api, I will update the code with the new API

Comment: I've also tried your login/pass with my browser and get a message saying "Sorry, your user ID or password is not correct; or your portal account is disabled."

Comment: You have also to post to the "action" URL of the form, that is: https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp?Summit=OK

Comment: Please give it another go it will work this time, sorry for the inconvenience last time. thanks

Comment: I have just logged in with my own scraping library. You have to give the hcUserID and hcPassword fields (instead of UserID and Password. Maybe a javascript changes your values to these hidden fields just before submitting the login form)

Comment: I will merge your script with does the POST with the mine. The POST gives a redirection to the internal page 'My Alerts'. It is better to perform an additional GET request. See (and try) my modified solution again.

Comment: thanks, 
eclipse is raising an syntax error on "System.out.println(new String(get.getResponseBody()));" 
"get.getResponseBody()" cannot be found on the library.

anyways, on this line 
"HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp");" gives an error of ClassCastException, java.net.CookiePolicy cannot cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

You don't use .NET web page, You must create .NET web service because only WebService have post and get method. You don't request Web Page. Web Page not receive your message and answer.

Comment: this is not my webpage, its my universities, what other option do i have?

Comment: When you login successfully, what did you see in the URL text. If text encrypted you can not anything. Because I explain before you need "web service".